# python for loop unexpectedly stopping

Tags: python, list, for-loop

new to python trying to create a program you can feed a .txt file and have the program perform a specific list of actions code below

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con
from tkinter import *
import re

File = open("data.txt", "r")
if File.mode == "r":
    myfile =File.read()

def Convert(string):
    li = list(string.split(" "))
    li = list(string.split("\n"))
    return li

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,1,1)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,1,1)

def wait(x):
    print(x)
    time.sleep(x)

  
instruccions = Convert(myfile)


    


for x in instruccions:
    if  "1" in x or "2" in x or "3" in x or "4" in x or "5" in x or "6" in x or "7" in x or "8" in x or "9" in x or "0" in x:
      x = list(x.split(","))
      if x[0] == "CL":
            action = (x[0])
            xcords = (int(x[1]))
            ycords = (int(x[2]))
            click(xcords,ycords)
      elif x[0] == "ST":
          TimeS = (int(x[1]))
          wait(TimeS)

            
        
    elif "1" not in x:
        
       if x == "CL":
           print("click")
       elif x == "PK":
           print("pressing key")
       elif x != "CL" or "PK":
           print("invalid key")


File.close
```

**the click function that doesn't require numbers will be set to click at the mouse current position**

the .txt file I'm feeding the program is

CL
CL,1600,600

ST,3

Cl,1600,400

Cl,1400,600

Cl,1600,400

Cl,1400,600

Cl,1600,400

to which I receive the output(including the a click at the called position)

click

3

invalid key

which I think is odd since the delay is correctly run and only running a series of clicks #to test this delete ST,3
doesn't seem to stop the program so I'm confused at what is stopping the program form running the rest of the clicks even if does get this invalid  key

I know its probably some rookie mistake or a lapse in judgment I apologize for my lacking python and English skills any other remark or criticism would be greatly appreciated like a better way to check for numbers instead of using   if  "1" in x or "2" in x or "3"...

Comment: Please note that "Cl" is not the same as "CL".  That's the essence of your problem.

Comment: Also, `elif x != "CL" or "PK":` does not do what you think it does.  Fortunately, you can simple replace that line with `else:`.

Comment: Also `File.close` doesn't do anything.  You wanted `File.close()`, but you don't even need that if the program is ending.

Comment: I'm not sure but at a first look, it seems to me to be related with the if conditionals. First you set `if "1" in x or "any_number" in x:`and then you use `elif "1" not in x:` what can be a bit contradictory, both expressions could be fulfilled or not at the same time.

Comment: My suggestion is to remove `if "any_number" in x:` and let the first conditional as `if  "1" in x:`and the second one as `elif "1" not in x:`but I don't know if it does properly what you want to do. Other way is to set the first conditional as `if "1" in x:` and the last one as `elif x or "2" in x or "3" in x or "4" in x or "5" in x or "6" in x or "7" in x or "8" in x or "9" in x or "0" in x:`or simply `else:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you want.

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import win32api, win32con

File = open("data.txt", "r")

def click(x=None,y=None):
    if x is not None:
        win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,1,1)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,1,1)

def wait(x):
    print(x)
    time.sleep(x)

for line in myfile:
    parts = line.strip().split(',')
    if parts[0] == 'ST':
        TimeS = (int(x[1]))
        wait(TimeS)
    elif parts[0] in ("CL","Cl"):
        if len(parts) == 1:
            print( "click current position" )
            click()
        else:
            xcords = int(parts[1])
            ycords = int(parts[2])
            print( f"click at {xcords},{ycords}" )
            click(xcords,ycords)
    elif parts[0] == "PK":
        print( "press key" )
    else:
        print( "unknown command" )
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some small change in code.
Feel free to test

```
import time
import win32api, win32con

with open("data.txt", "r") as File:  
    # handles the closing of File automatically after 'with' block execution

    myfile = File.read()

    def Convert(string):
        string = string.replace("\n", " ")
        li = string.split(" ")

        return li


    def click(x, y):
        win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 1, 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 1, 1)
        print("clicked")


    def wait(x):
        print(x)
        time.sleep(x)

    instructions = Convert(myfile)

    number_list = [str(i) for i in range(0, 10)]

    for each_instruction in instructions:
        each_sub_instruction = []

        for each_number in number_list:
            if each_number in each_instruction:
                each_sub_instruction = each_instruction.split(",")

                if each_sub_instruction[0] == "CL":
                    action = (each_sub_instruction[0])
                    xcords = (int(each_sub_instruction[1]))
                    ycords = (int(each_sub_instruction[2]))
                    click(xcords, ycords)

                elif each_instruction[0] == "ST":
                    TimeS = (int(each_instruction[1]))
                    wait(TimeS)

                break

        if each_instruction == "CL":
            print("click")
        elif each_instruction == "PK":
            print("pressing key")
        elif each_sub_instruction and each_sub_instruction[0] != "CL" and each_sub_instruction[0] != "PK":
            print("invalid key")
```